# jquery listen all elements with same class

Tags: jquery, css

When the click is performed on any of the elements of the grid, an ajax window opens, this ajax div has a wrapper.

I would like to invoke a click event on element `.eg-ajax-a-button` and add `ajax-wrapper-on` class to `ajax-wrapper-off`.  The code works only with the first entry, how can I make it work with all elements?  They all share the class `eg-ajax-a-button`

I have tried with

```
var actionitem = document.querySelector('.eg-ajax-a-button')[0];
```

this is the full code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  var actionitem = document.querySelector('.eg-ajax-a-button');

  actionitem.style.cursor = 'pointer';

  actionitem.onclick = function() {
  $("#ajax-wrapper-off").addClass("ajax-wrapper-on");
  };

  });
```

I have tried with a Jquery version as a commentor said in the comments section there was a issue with mixing jquery and js, i'm in the first steps in this language.
tried, but doesnt work

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
     $(".eg-ajax-a-button").click(function() 
     {
       $("#ajax-wrapper-off").addClass("ajax-wrapper-on");
     };    
  });
```

Comment: Stop mixing jQuery and plain javascript in that way, and it solves itself.

Comment: FYI, `querySelector` only gets the ***first*** matching element, to get all of them you'd use `querySelectorAll`, or just jQuery `$('.eg-ajax-a-button')`

Comment: can you advice a correct sintax? I'm really a novice.

Comment: As a no-vice, you should read doc of methods you are using and more importantly, trying to understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 $('.eg-ajax-a-button').on('click', function(){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your using jQuery as your javascript library of choice you should follow their documentation on doing all things jQuery.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Below Is how you normally bootstrap a jQuery project.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    });
```

and if your selecting classes or id's jQuery has it's own built in selector for both.

```
$( ".myClass" );

$( "#myId" );
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/